# Как вернуть текущее значение переменной или поля, а не объекта из метода spy мока?

Tags: java, mockito

Есть тест:

```
 private DataJpa myObject = new DataJpa();
 private DaoService daoService = mock(DaoService.class);
 private RestServiceImpl service = spy(RestServiceImpl.class);

 @Before // I've tried @BeforeClass too
 public void init(){

   service.setDaoService(daoService);
   when(daoService.selectObject(anyString())).thenReturn(myObject);
}

@Test
public void test1(){

   Response registerFirstResponse = service.registerDevice(serialNumber, token, registrationDeviceRequest);

   createMyObjectJpa(field1,field2,field3);

   Response registerSecondResponse = service.registerDevice(serialNumber, token, registrationDeviceRequest);

   assertEquals(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode(), registerFirstResponse.getStatus());
   assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), registerSecondResponse.getStatus());
}

 private void createJpa(field1,field2,field3){
        myObject.setDeviceId(field1);
        myObject.setPushToken(field2); 
}
```

И мой `registerDevice` метод внутри `service`

```
 public Response registerDevice(String serialNumber, String token, String registrationDeviceRequest){
    DataJpa jpa=daoService.selectObject(serialNumber);
        if(jpa==null){
           //here I must fulfill my jpa 
            dataJpa = StaticUtils.createJpa(field1,field2,field3);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
        }else{
             return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        }
}
```

Так вот, почему-то после первого метода `myObject` заполняется данными, то есть `testField`, но вот при втором вызове, я ожидаю, что в переменной уже будет это значение, а там снова `null` и `myObject` заполняется повторно.

Суть моего теста в том, чтобы при втором вызове, у меня случилось исключение.

Как сделать так, чтобы объект сохранил значение ?

**EDIT**

Необходимо и достаточно

```
   public class Class1 {

    String field1;
    String field2;
    String field3;

    public Class1() {
    }

    public Class1(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }
}


---------------


import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class Class2 {

    Class1 class1;

    public Response testClass() {

        if (class1 == null) {
            class1 = getMyObjectFromMethod();
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_MODIFIED).build();
        }
    }

    public Class1 getMyObjectFromMethod() {

        Class1 class1 = new Class1("field1", "field2", "field3");
        return class1;
    }
}


---------------

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class TestClass {

    Class1 class1;
    Class2 class2 = spy(Class2.class);

    @Before
    public void init() {
        class1 = new Class1();
        when(class2.getMyObjectFromMethod()).thenReturn(null).thenReturn(class1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {

        Response responseFirstClass1 = class2.testClass();

        class1 = fulfilClass();
        Response responseSecondClass1 = class2.testClass();

        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), responseFirstClass1.getStatus());
        assertEquals(Response.Status.NOT_MODIFIED.getStatusCode(), responseSecondClass1.getStatus());

    }

    private Class1 fulfilClass() {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1("field11", "field22", "field33");
        return class1;
    }
}
```

[ассоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57058220/9719337)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96296/discussion-between-dred-and-default-locale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда Вы передаете в [`thenReturn`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenReturn-T-) значение (null или объект), то будет возвращаться это значение. Если объект изменится, то эти изменения будут отражены. Но если оригинальной переменной будет присвоен новый объект, то это ни на что не повлияет.

Чтобы каждый раз возвращать значение переменной можете использовать [`thenAnswer`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-):

```
when(daoService.selectJpa(serialNumber)).thenAnswer(i -> jpa);
```

или [`doAnswer`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-) (так реальный метод не будет вызываться):

```
doAnswer(i -> jpa).when(daoService).selectJpa(anyString());
```